# How to submit command with image buffer as payload from another thread

Tags: rust, druid-rs

I am trying to download image using another thread and to send downloaded bytes in ImageBuf object to main thread using Druid command system.
The code I am using is:

```
let event_sink = ctx.get_external_handle();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let content_bytes = download_bytes("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/generic-drug-box-picture-id1054301628");
        let raw_content_bytes : &[u8] = content_bytes.as_ref();
        let image_buffer = ImageBuf::from_data(raw_content_bytes).expect("Failed to store bytes into image buffer");

        event_sink.submit_command(UPDATE_IMAGE_COMMAND, image_buffer, Target::from(image_widget_id));
    });
```

The last line throws an error message saying:

```
the trait bound `Box<()>: From<ImageBuf>` is not satisfied
the following implementations were found:
<Box<(dyn StdError + 'a)> as From<E>>
<Box<(dyn StdError + 'static)> as From<&str>>
<Box<(dyn StdError + 'static)> as From<Cow<'a, str>>>
<Box<(dyn StdError + 'static)> as From<anyhow::Error>>
and 25 others
required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<Box<()>>` for `ImageBuf`
```

I am not sure what this really means, I have been looking through examples and tried wrapping image_buffer into box but none of it have helped so far.

Do note that in Druid examples there is one example(blocking_function) that sends raw number(u32) as payload, but when I try to put hardcoded number instead of image_buffer in my code, I still get the same error message.

Comment: With the information you provided, it may be difficult to provide a solution (what's `UPDATE_IMAGE_COMMAND`?). I can however give you a way to get a better error message: Currently, rustc has inferred the parameter `T` of [`submit_command`](https://docs.rs/druid/latest/druid/struct.ExtEventSink.html#method.submit_command) to be `()`. You can overwrite that inference by specifying `.submit_command::<ImageBuf>(…)`. You'll likely get an error message that explains why rustc thought that `T` must be `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Add generic argument: `pub(crate) const UPDATE_IMAGE_COMMAND: Selector<ImageBuf> = Selector::new("update_image");`

Thanks to comment from [@Caesar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108954/how-to-submit-command-with-image-buffer-as-payload-from-another-thread?noredirect=1#comment125700519_71108954) i applied `.submit_command::<ImageBuf>(…)` and figured out that druid `Selector` have generic type on them which determines what kind of payload can be sent with the finally generated `Command`.
Default type for `Selector` is `<T = ()>` so the fix for my problem was just to add `ImageBuf` as generic argument for selector as shown in the code snippet above